# asp.net core windows authentication on local iis

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, kestrel-http-server

I created default asp.net core application from defaut template. I chose Windows Authentication option during porcess of creation of new project [(here is what i did)](http://take.ms/Dl8HB). When i run app on issexpress, it works like a charm.

When i moved app onto local iis it works, but it does not get user info. I enabled windows authentication in windows features. But it shows me empty User.Identity.Name. I tried to add this lines to web.config

```
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
```

Tried to turn on windows authentication from IIS Manager. I dont know what else can be wrong. What am i missing?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, tried the same things...still no success.  Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve this issue. I turned on windows authentication feature on local iis and after that local authentication worked like a charm. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2013/11/05/installingadding-iis-windows-authentication-feature-in-windows-8/) is a good article how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In web.config, did you put

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

in system.web sector as well?